# CMS and displaying custom data

Tags: frameworks, content-management-system

I'm looking for good CMS (preferably PHP due to current server capabilities), which is quite user-friendly and is able to at least present custom data from DB with minimum effort.

I would be very glad to know CMSes, which you have experience with already. Drupal isn't working for me, due to problems with Map CCK.

Some explanation why the CMS is good for this solution is warmly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Umbraco and I LOVE it. It just lets you do just about anything. You can have custom templates, custom code, code-behind files and user controls. It is the most developer friendly CMS I have worked with. It uses actual asp.net masterpages and content placeholders and regular js and css files. I have very good things to say about Umbraco  in the customization department. In several projects I have custom data taken from custom tables, and it works great. Hosting packages are cheap these days and server hardware and software is also getting cheaper by the minute. If you really want to stick to PHP, a designer I'm working with told me that ModX has similar functionality for PHP:

http://modx.com/

Comment: Yep, Umbraco doesn't help me out. I got a Linux server, so Umbraco isn't going to work. ModX looks promising, however. I will check it out tomorrow.

Comment: After all, I went with MODx. However, don't expect a lot less coding there ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the chance to work briefly with [Concrete5](http://www.concrete5.org/), and it's very nice!

Concrete5 is designed primarily to do the job of being a CMS, but it also follows an MVC architecture like Ruby on Rails, Django, and other popular Web application frameworks do, making it easy to customize in a clean and maintainable way.

As with other PHP-based solutions, it's a cinch to deploy, and runs on almost any Web host.

Comment: After a quick look-in, I must admit it looks nice. I will test it tomorrow.